# Equivalent Simple Injector .Register invocations

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I have an object whose constructor requires a primitive. I register it using a delegate (please excuse the contrived example).

```cs
container.Register<Account>(() => new Account(1000M), Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

I register this type `Account` as the implementation of an interface `IAccount`. When doing so using the call marked `B` below, SimpleInjector's `.Verify()` complains:

```cs
/* B */container.Register<IAccount, Account>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

> The constructor of type Account contains parameter 'funds'
> of type decimal, which can not be used for constructor injection
> because it is a value type. (Parameter 'TImplementation')

Using the call marked `A` instead has no such issues and works as intended:

```cs
/* A */container.Register<IAccount>(() => container.GetInstance<Account>(), Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

I seem to have incorrectly assumed that `A` and `B` would be *effectively* equivalent. What have I missed? Why does `B` fail to utilise the registered delegate for creation of the `Account` instance? Thank you.

(File below is LINQPad (.linq) format)

```cs
<Query Kind="Program">
  <NuGetReference>SimpleInjector</NuGetReference>
  <Namespace>SimpleInjector</Namespace>
</Query>

void Main()
{
    var containerRegistry = new ContainerRegistry();
    Console.WriteLine("Balance = " + containerRegistry.GetInstance<Account>().Balance);
}

public class ContainerRegistry
{
    private readonly Container container = new Container();

    public ContainerRegistry()
    {
        container.Register<Account>(() => new Account(1000M), Lifestyle.Singleton);

        /* A */container.Register<IAccount>(() => container.GetInstance<Account>(), Lifestyle.Singleton);
        /* B */container.Register<IAccount, Account>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

        container.Verify();
    }
    
    [Obsolete] public TInstanceType GetInstance<TInstanceType>() where TInstanceType : class
        => container.GetInstance<TInstanceType>();
}

public class Account : IAccount
{
    public decimal Balance => funds;
    
    private readonly decimal funds;
    
    public Account(decimal funds)
    {
        this.funds = funds;
    }
}

public interface IAccount
{
    decimal Balance { get; }
}
```

Comment: What is the function of Account in yoyr application? Is it a class that contains behavior, or rather a domain entity? And what is fund? Is that a constant value or do you have many accounts with each a different value for fund?

Comment: Hi @Steven. In reality, `Account` here is a service; the example is contrived just for brevity/simplicity. I have done a little research (saw your #246 issue in the SimpleInjector repo on GitHub) and have seen that the primitive ctor param can be solved in a few ways, and that while generally delegates should be avoided, they can be used in this scenario. I think I understand the complaint of .Verify() under normal circumstances; I just don't understand it here when I have told SimpleInjector how to instantiate the type in question, especially because the other .Register() invocation works.

Comment: It would be good to use actual names and meanings in your post, because the right answer might depend on this.

Comment: Can you describe what fund represents? Is this a runtime value that can change, or rather a value that stays constant while the application runs?

Comment: `funds`, the ctor param, represents a value which initialises a quantity in the object that changes during runtime; put differently, `funds` itself does not change, but the quantity it initialises does. This differs from the code sample in the question (again for brevity).

Comment: Why do you need to register both Account and IAccount? Do you have a consumer that requires access to the Account instance, bypassing its interface?

Comment: [Hope I've understood correctly] The consumer(s) accepts `IAccount` in its ctor. I want to register `Account` as the implementation that the consumer(s) receives. I have to register `Account` explicitly, with the delegate, as it has a primitive ctor param which SimpleInjector does not know how to navigate otherwise. (I am aware of some alternatives, e.g. `AccountConfiguration` object ctor param, e.g. pushing the ctor param out of ctor and using `.RegisterInitializer()` but thought the ctor param was simpler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
container.Register<IAccount>(
    () => new Account(1000M),
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

A call to `Register<T, R>()` always applies auto-wiring (by design), which means that R is created by the container by calling its constructor. It will, therefore, not reuse the overload with the delegate. That's considered a different registration. That's simply how the API works.

Comment: Thanks @Steven. This works, but with my question, I had hoped to understand the issue better - as explained, the `.Register` call marked `A` already 'works' (even if, admittedly, it is not the idiomatic form). Why does `Register<T, R>()` fail to use a delegate already registered for the creation of `R`, when `T` is requested? Though your answer works and may be the idiomatic way to approach the problem with SimpleInjector, I still don't understand why the delegate is not used. Bug? Design limitation? Holding it wrong? Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me through this.

Comment: A call to `Register<T, R>()` always applies auto-wiring (by design), which means that `R` is created by the container by calling its constructor. It will, therefore, not reuse the overload with the delegate. That's considered a different registration. What you are seeing is certainly not a bug, and I don't consider it a limitation. That's simply not how the API works.

Comment: That's the info I needed - thanks again @Steven :) I also did not mean to imply a bug or undesirable limitation was at play - just enumerating possibilities to try and make my question and the info I was after a bit clearer. I was in fact holding it wrong.